# Use exams2pdf or a modified solution.tex template to print solutions not another answer list

Tags: latex, r-exams

I am trying to create a solution pdf for an exam but all I need for it is a simple marked box and not the answer list that follows. For example, I just want the first page from the following compilation and nothing else.

```
library(exams)

exams2pdf(list(
  "boxplots",
  c("tstat", "ttest", "confint"),
  c("regression", "anova"),
  "scatterplot",
  "relfreq"
), template = "solution"
)
```

I don't have a strong grasp of the Latex language so when I try removing for example

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
```

or

```
% \exinput{exercises}
```

It doesn't compile and just complains about a missing item etc

Which part of solution.tex can I remove that retains just the first page?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Hi Sam just updated as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** You need to delete all of the following lines from your copy of `solution.tex`:

```
\newpage

\begin{enumerate}

%% \exinput{exercises}

\end{enumerate}
```

**Details:** This LaTeX code starts a new page and includes an enumerated list for the individual exercises. The `\exinput{exercises}` is replaced with each of the `{question}` (and optionally `{solution}`) environments which then produces an `\item` for each question. So if you just remove the `\exinput` line, LaTeX complains about missing items because the `{enumerate}` list is empty.

**Documentation:** More details for `exams2pdf()` and its LaTeX templates can be found in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`.